# UNIX-Shell Scripting

Tags: unix, shell, shell-script

While executing the below script, I'm getting an error:

**Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected.**

```
sudo su - user1 -c "cd $HOME ; tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar `cat /tmp/$LOGNAME/List`  "
```

where List file contains the name of some other files.

Please help me out with some solution.

Regards,
Sumit

Comment: commandlinefu.com

Comment: Standard debugging technique: break down the problem until you find the smallest example that causes it.  What happens if you say `sudo su - user1 -c date`?  How about `sudo su - user1 -c sh` and then type `cd $HOME ; tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar \`cat /tmp/$LOGNAME/List\`` into the shell?

Comment: question also on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17307119/7552)

Comment: Why the `cd $HOME` ? You already have an `-f $HOME/mine.tar` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is expanding things too early.

Does `$LOGNAME` have a `(` in it? Or the contents of `/tmp/$LOGNAME/List`?

Bash will expand `$HOME` and `$LOGNAME` before they get passed to `su` - when `su` then tries to pass them off to `sh` or `bash`, they have improper tokens in them.

Answer (score 0):

Please make that single line commands to multiple line and execute, like write this to run.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd $HOME
tar -cvf $HOME/mine.tar
cat /tmp/$LOGNAME/List
```

Give execution permission (`chmod +x run.sh`) and run that script as `sh path to the file(run.sh)`

e.g: sh /home/run.sh

Comment: Two minor points:
1) No need to make it executable or add the shebang line if you run it with `sh scriptfile`.
2) sh might not be bash, so in this example `sh run.sh` and `/home/run.sh` might run under different shells. This matters for more complex scripts which may try to use bash-only features.

Comment: I mention that in the case of bash.